# Desktop HTML Kiosk with Touch support

Tags: javascript, html, windows, touch, kiosk

I have to develop an application in html/js for a kiosk. 
This Kiosk will be displayed on a Windows Touch screen, with "Windows Touch" capability.

It seems that there is some frameworks to use the gestures on mobile plateform, but I found nothing for a Desktop with a Touch Screen.

Is there a mean to use a "Slide gesture" on an html page, (for example to slide a big panel), opening the page in a browser in Windows 7, on a Desktop computer?

Thanx in advance for your help

Comment: I've never tried it on a desktop browser, but an idea could be to look into jQuery mobile and similar mobile frameworks. Nowadays, there's really not much difference in mobile / tablet / desktop use. The big differentiation is in touch vs non-touch.

Comment: I just found a lib that works!: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/
I've tested with a Windows Touch Desktop (Window 7), and I could use "Sweep" gesture perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for proper touch events in the browser is a browser-by-browser consideration. In IE 10 and 11, Microsoft have abstracted the concept away from Mouse and Touch events to what they call [Pointer events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn433244(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Gesture events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn433243(v=vs.85).aspx) respectively.

With your specific request for a "slide gesture" for interacting with a carousel, [there's a specific IE Blog article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/10/22/enabling-new-interoperable-panning-experiences-through-the-css-scrolling-snap-points-specification.aspx).